# Reference to slice of an array

Tags: javascript, slice

How to get the reference to a slice of an array?

```
var A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
A.mySlice = function(l, h){return this.slice(l,h)};

var B = A.mySlice(1,5); // ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

It works for direct slices derived from A. But, how to get it for all slices derived? (in this case for B)

```
B.mySlice = function(l, h){return this.slice(l,h)};

A[3] = 33;
A.mySlice(1,5) // ["b", "c", 33, "e"] => ok
B.mySlice(0,3) // ["b", "c", "d"] => I would want ["b", "c", 33]
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but I'd like to see what others come up with,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with native JS arrays (well, not in a straightforward manner anyway).

I think the cleanest approach would be going back and using custom objects to represent the slices. Perhaps something along these lines:

```
function ArraySlice(arr, lo, hi){
    this.arr = arr;
    this.lo = lo;
    this.hi = hi;
    this.length = hi - lo;
};
ArraySlice.prototype._contains = function(ix){
    return this.lo + ix < this.hi;
};
ArraySlice.prototype.get = function(ix){
    if (this._contains(ix)){
        return this.arr[this.lo + ix];
    }else{
        return; //undefined
    }
};
ArraySlice.prototype.set = function(ix, value){
    if (this._contains(ix)){
        return (this.arr[this.lo + ix] = value);
    }else{
        return; //undefined
    }
};

var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var b = new ArraySlice(a, 1, 3);

a[2] = 17;
console.log( b.get(1) );
```

Of course, this loses the convenient `[]` syntax and the objects aren't arrays anymore but subclassing Array is annoying and error prone and I don't believe there is a cross-browser way to do operator overloading.

Comment: @Truth: Thank you. Take these 128 pieces of candy for your trouble.

Comment: Candy? I want Master Balls! :D

Comment: I've no problem about non using [] syntax

Comment: I suspect you could use a proxy that handles `[]` syntax by handling the `get` trap.  For that matter, you could do this without a separate class if you don't mind polluting the Array prototype.

Answer (score 3):

`slice()` copies elements to a new array.

So, in your example, `A` and `B` are two completely different arrays. So, changing elements in one does not affect another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only possible solution I see:

- extend Array class and store all array data in a singleton class instance
- create a unique identifier (UID) when you first create a new array
- use that identifier when you are trying to get data from singleton
- use that same identifier when you're making a slice

This may however break lots of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible in Javascript.  This line `var B = A.mySlice(1,5);` sets B to an array object containting a slice of A's numbers.  It has no reference to A.  It's just an array object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as clean, since you'd be dealing with function objects, but you could wrap the calls to chain back up the original array using closures:

```
var A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
A.mySlice = function (l, h) { return function() { return this.slice(l, h); }; };

var B = A.mySlice(1, 5); // B() will resolve to ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
B.mySlice = function (l, h) { return function() { return this().slice(1, h) }; };

A[3] = 33;
A.mySlice(1, 5)() // ["b", "c", 33, "e"]
B.mySlice(0, 3)() // ["b", "c", 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

I overengineered a solution to this using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  This will behave more or less like a pointer to some position within an `int[]` in `C++` would.  It does this by proxying the original array, keeping track of the start and end indices, and trapping `get` and `set` with versions that reference the relative index within the original array.

```js
Array.prototype.slicePtr = function(startIdx, endIdx = this.length) {
  if (startIdx < 0) {
    startIdx = this.length - startIdx - 1;
  }

  if (endIdx < 0) {
    endIdx = this.length - endIdx;
  }

  if (startIdx > endIdx) {
    throw new Error('startIdx must not be greater than endIdx');
  }

  endIdx = endIdx == null ? this.length : endIdx;

  const self = this;

  function contains(idx) {
    return idx > 0 && idx < endIdx;
  }

  const proxy = new Proxy(this, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      // symbols can't be converted to numbers, so handle them first
      if (typeof prop === 'symbol') {
        switch (prop) {
          case Symbol.iterator:
            return function*() {
              for (let i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++) {
                yield self[i];
              }
            }
        }
      }

      const idx = startIdx + Number(prop);
      if (!isNaN(idx)) {
        if (!contains(idx)) {
          return undefined;
        }

        return Reflect.get(target, idx, receiver);
      }

      switch (prop) {
        case 'splice':
          return function splice(start, delCount, ...items) {
            endIdx += items.length - delCount;
            return self.splice(start + startIdx, delCount, ...items);
          }

        case 'length':
          return endIdx - startIdx;

        case 'pop':
          return function pop() {
            return proxy.splice(proxy.length - 1, 1)[0];
          }

        case 'push':
          return function push(...items) {
            proxy.splice(proxy.length, 0, ...items);
            return proxy[proxy.length - 1];
          }

        case 'shift':
          return function shift() {
            return proxy.splice(0, 1)[0];
          }

        case 'unshift':
          return function unshift(...items) {
            proxy.splice(startIdx, 0, ...items);
            return proxy[proxy.length - 1];
          }
      }

      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    },

    set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
      if (typeof prop !== 'symbol') {
        const idx = startIdx + Number(prop);
        if (!isNaN(idx)) {
          if (Number.isFinite(idx) && Number.isInteger(idx) && Number(prop) >= proxy.length) {
            endIdx = idx + 1;
          }

          return Reflect.set(target, idx, value, receiver);
        }
      }

      switch (prop) {
        case 'length':
          endIdx = startIdx + value;
          if (endIdx > self.length) {
            self.length = endIdx;
          }

          return value;
      }

      return Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver);
    },
  });

  return proxy;
}

/////////////
//  TESTS  //
/////////////

let array = [];
let slice = [];

const fnRegex = /\(?\w*\)? => (?:\{\}|(.*)?);?$/;
const resultsTbl = $('#results tbody');
const makeRow = (fn) => {
  const row = $('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>').append($('<code>').text(fn.toString().replace(fnRegex, '$1'))))
    .append($('<td>').append($('<code>').text(JSON.stringify(fn(), null, 2))))
    .append($('<td>').append($('<code>').text(JSON.stringify(array, null, 2))))
    .append($('<td>').append($('<code>').text(JSON.stringify(slice, null, 2))));
  resultsTbl.append(row);
};

[
  () => array = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  () => slice = array.slicePtr(2, 5),
  () => slice[2],
  () => slice[0] = 1000,
  () => slice.length = 4,
  () => slice.push(20),
  () => slice.shift(),
  () => slice.indexOf(4),
  () => slice.filter(v => !(v % 2)),
  () => slice.map(v => v / 2),
  () => slice.splice(1, 2, 30, 40, 50),
  () => slice = slice.slicePtr(1, 4),
  () => slice[1] = 60,
  () => slice.fill(0),
  () => JSON.stringify(slice),
  () => slice.toString(),
  () => slice[7] = 'end',
].forEach(fn => makeRow(fn));
```

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
  padding: 4px 2px;
}
td {
  padding-left: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 3em;
}
tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #eee;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
  <thead><tr><th>Code</th><th>Result</th><th><code>array</code></th><th><code>[ ...slice ]</code></th></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The only bit I don't have (I **think**) is `console.log(slice)`; it always prints `array`.  [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643071/override-output-of-console-log-in-javascript), there is no way to override what `console.log()` and `console.dir()` will print for a given object.

It's quite possible I have left some things out that I just didn't think of, and I never tested `copyWithin()` because I still can't quite wrap my head around what it actually does.  Might work though.  ‍♀️